# How to override Vuetify text-field underline from scoped style in single file component?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to change the default color of the underline border for an unfocused [regular](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/) `v-text-field` from the scoped style of a single file component, but I can't override it. I've overridden the font size for the labels of the text-fields with a deep selector on the label class like this:

```
.v-text-field >>> .v-label {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

...and this works. Chrome dev tools shows me that the class responsible for the underline is:

```
.theme--light.v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot::before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42);
}
```

I've tried the following variations, but none of them have worked:

```
/* .theme--light.v-text-field >>> .v-input__control >>> .v-input__slot::before { */
/* .theme--light.v-text-field > .v-input__control >>> .v-input__slot::before { */
/* .v-text-field >>> .v-input__control >>> .v-input__slot::before { */
/* .v-text-field > .v-input__control >>> .v-input__slot::before { */
/* .v-input__control >>> .v-input__slot::before { */
.v-input__slot::before {
  border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Incidentally, I'm only doing this because there doesn't seem to be any props exposed on `v-text-field` that allow the border color to be changed (which I'm surprised at), unless I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `v-text-field` does not expose any prop to change border color. However, you can still use deep selectors to override border-color. In the first example you have used `>>>` to override font-size. Same applies for border-color as well.

**Example**

```css
.v-text-field >>> .v-input__slot::before  { border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important; }
```

or

```css
::v-deep .v-input__slot::before  { border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important; }
```

works even with

```css
>>> .v-input__slot::before  { border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important; }
```

More information about [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)